# PostgreSQL CASE WHEN THEN ELSE END error

Tags: postgresql

I was working well when we are using v9.1, but after upgrading to v9.4, the following failed.

```
SELECT   a.account_id 
         ( 
                select round(cast(sum(WHEN c.transaction_type = 'Ranger' THEN c.original_currency ELSE c.original_currency * -1
         end)) AS NUMERIC), 
                       2) 
FROM     account_transaction AS c 
WHERE    a.account_id = c.account_id 
GROUP BY c.account_id) 
AS 
  balance_amount 
  FROM account 
AS 
  a LEFT JOIN account_type 
AS 
  b ON a.account_type_id = b.account_type_id 
  WHERE ( 
    b.description >= 'Boomberang' AND b.description <= 'Boomberang' 
  );
```

syntax error at or near `WHEN`

I have googled but couldn't solve the problem. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the `CASE` keyword, try this instead:

```
(CASE WHEN c.transaction_type = 'Ranger' THEN c.original_currency ELSE c.original_currency * -1 END)
```

Comment: You are right. That word is missing. It should be CASE WHEN. I am sorry for my confusion. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean CASE WHEN instead of WHEN?

Comment: Yes it is CASE WHEN not WHEN. Thank you for pointing it out too.